# Error building Android project in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to Cordova and I am trying to build my project, which was previously working.  I believe I have a bug.  I am not very experienced with the terminal so I don't know how to resolve this.  I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling cordova, as well as updating it with no success. Here is my error:

```
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/joshuaoconnor/Desktop/PBBars/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/joshuaoconnor/Desktop/PBBars/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

and here is the full image of the terminal
[image]

Comment: your android is not added to path add android tools, platform tool into your path.. it will work

Comment: how do I do this?  Do i type a specific command in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure an answer out on my own.  Coming from a complete beginner with no experience with bash profile, I was lost with your instructions (no offense).  To fix this issue, learn how to edit your PATH environment variables.  I used this tutorial (http://hathaway.cc/post/69201163472/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac) which showed how to do it with textedit.  After I learned how to edit my PATH variables, I added

```
export ANDROID_TOOLS="/Users/joshuaoconnor/Documents/sdk/tools"

export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/Users/joshuaoconnor/Documents/sdk/platform-tools"
```

to my BASH profile.  Sithys and Logains answers did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your running in a standard "*beginners*" issue by using cordova or phonegap - but no problem, we are here to help you ;-)

**The Terminal tells you, that:**

```
ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH.
```

So, you `$PATH` is a `SystemVariable` which "*saves*" pathes to important files and folders. All files, which are part of the `SystemVariable $PATH` can be called via your Terminal. So because i don't know, which OS you are using, i'm going to post two solutions. One for each, mac and windows.

---

**Before you start**: The `PATH` is a `SystemVariable` which **is needed** as it is. Another folder can be added by a `:` which seperates the single folders and pathes inside your `PATH`. If you do anything wrong there, **your system may never work correct again without reinstalling it** - be carefull and do not delete any of the `PATHs` content which is already there.

---

### **What do i need in my Path? (especially for Cordova/PhoneGap now)**

So you need three things in your `Path`:

1. `%ANDROID_HOME%`
2. `tools`
3. `platform-tools`

---

### **How can i see my actual `$PATH`?**

1. `echo $PATH` on a mac
2. `echo %PATH%` on windows

---

### **How to set up the `PATH` Variable on Windows**

1. Select your Computer from the Start Menu.
2. From the Contextmenu select `System properties`.
3. After that select the `advanced` tab.
4. In that section you click on `Environment Variables`.
5. So in the section `System variables` you're going to find the `Path` which can be edited over there.

### **How to set up the `PATH` Variable on Mac OS X Yosemite**

1. Open your `terminal` and go on like this:
2. vi $HOME/.bash_profile
3. Add a line there with this content:
4. `export PATH=$PATH:new/dir1/:dir2:/dir/path/new`

This changes will be loaded after a reboot - to apply them immediatly after you changed it, save and close your file and type `source $HOME/.bash_profile`.

---

If you have any further questions, let me know - i'm going to edit my answer than.

By the way: There is a great Documentation on how to install Android-Platform on Windows machines. It can be found here, inside the Apache Cordova Docs -> [Android - Shell-Tools Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide_platforms_android_tools.md.html#Android%20Shell%20Tool%20Guide)

Comment: I went to the terminal and added vi $HOME/.bash_profile, and it came back with "E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "~/.bash_profile.swp"....
Swap file "~/.bash_profile.swp" already exists!"..

Comment: Do I copy and paste export PATH=$PATH:new/dir1/:dir2:/dir/path/new or do I use my own files?  Im sorry, I am extremely confused here.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `local.properties` file and add the correct path to your sdk `sdk.dir=/home/somewhere/android-sdk/sdk`

I would suggest to generate the project using cordova but build it using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), since you will probably want to tune one or two things on your android project anyway.

---

EDITED:

It seems you are on windows, so a quick way would be to [set an Environment Variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) called `ANDROID_HOME` pointing to the directory where you downloaded the android sdk as per the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html)

Either that or the steps stated on the documentation:

> To modify the PATH environment on Windows 7:
>
> Click on the Start menu in the lower-left corner of the desktop,
>   right-click on Computer, then select Properties.
>
> Select Advanced System Settings in the column on the left.
>
> In the resulting dialog box, press Environment Variables.
>
> Select the PATH variable and press Edit.
>
> Append the following to the PATH based on where you installed the SDK,
>   for example:
>
> `;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools`

Comment: Look at the users stats. He also said, that he is new to this so your answer is not enough.

Comment: Agree with @Sithys, and I don't think build with Android Studio is a good advice, you don't need it at all

Comment: sorry about that. Edited (although I do think that eventually Android Studio is, while not absolutely necessary, quite helpful for better platform integration)

Comment: Yes and now you posted a link to a windows XP documentation... i provided a detailed answer.

Comment: And I applaud your commitment. You really don't need to be so harsh about it , and the solution was actually on the cordova documentation I also linked : \

Comment: You linked the solution to cordova 4.0 which is a whole number before the actual version 5.1.1. But it's now problem Logain, i'm fine with your answer :) sorry that it sounds like that!

Comment: In that case, the missing part was then the `adt-bundle\sdk\tools` on your path.  Which allows executing the build command. The local.properties is used when the build is launched by other tools (i.e.:  android studio, so it doesn't need to depend on your windows path).

Comment: How do I add adt-bundle\sdk\tools to my path?  Do I add it to the local.properties file?  I'm very lost....

Comment: Follow the steps I quoted, or the ones on [the docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html)